# How to provide parameterized mockStore in ngrx in component spec file

Tags: angular, jasmine, ngrx, ngrx-store

**Providing the mock store for the parameterized selector still the property of this.currentCompany is null**

```
In Component.ts file



 this.store.select(fromEmployee.selectCompanies(companyID)).subscribe(selectedCompany)=>{
    this.currentCompany=selectedCompany;
    }

in Spec.ts file

const companyMock={...};

provideMockStore({
initialState:..,
selectors:[
{selector:fromEmployee.selectCompanies(123),value: companyMock}
]
})
```

Comment: make sure the initialState matches with your selector, that's probably why you are getting `null`, for example, in initialState, do you have a company with 123 id?

Comment: @Andres2142 yes the initial State contains it